# Modify label of a winform from console application

Tags: .net, winforms, label, .net-4.8

I have the following question. Let me put it in context: I have a winform in the .NET Framework, with a label. In a different project, which is a console application, I want to be able to access the label and modify its text with one provided by the console application. To note, the winform is opened first and the console application is executed on demand with the text as a parameter to update the form label
I have tried many options that I have found in searches on the internet and here in the forum, but none of them have worked for me.
I wonder if it is possible?
Any suggestions, ideas or similar.

Comment: There are many ways of doing this; system services, network services, IP, remoting, named pipes, message queues, shared files, and others. Which way is best for you depends on specifics about your applications and how they work. Which you haven't told us.

Comment: For example, with named pipes I have been unable to prevent the pipe from closing once the information is received by the server.

Comment: I am aware that this is not possible with system services, they run in a different session than a Windows form and you cannot interact with them directly.

Answer (score 1):

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, string lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool UpdateWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

    [DllImport("user32")]
    static extern int GetDC(int hwnd);

    [DllImport("user32")]
    static extern int ReleaseDC(int hwnd, int hdc);

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        const uint WM_SETTEXT = 0x000C;
        const uint WM_PAINT = 0x000F;

        Process p = Process.GetProcessesByName("TestApp1")[0];
        AutomationElement el = AutomationElement.FromHandle(p.MainWindowHandle);
        AutomationElementCollection aryel = el.FindAll(TreeScope.Descendants, new AndCondition(new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.IsControlElementProperty, true), new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Text))) ;
        if (aryel.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (AutomationElement t in aryel)
            {
                switch (t.Current.AutomationId)
                {
                    case "label_a":
                        SendMessage(new IntPtr(t.Current.NativeWindowHandle), WM_SETTEXT, IntPtr.Zero, "KKKKK");
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It works, but indiscriminately, if I have several labels, how can I differentiate them?

Comment: Try using the current data in automationelement.